# Freeing memory for a complicated data structure in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, free, complex-data-types

(This is an attempt to condense another question I have posted earlier. This is a large program so please bear with me, I have identified and distilled it to the components I am showing here.)

I am working with a dictionary data structure, which is a table, that is an array of linked lists. (dictionary -> table -> array -> (array[i] is a node in a linked list))

Defined like this:

```
// Data type for nodes in linked list
typedef struct list_node {
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN]; // Word, as a null-terminated string
    struct list_node *next;  // next in chain     
} list_node_t;

// Data type for a hash table. Use chaining for collisions, so array of list_nodes
typedef struct {
    list_node_t **array; // base array for hash table
    unsigned int length; // Length of base array
} table_t;

// Data type for a dictionary
typedef struct {
    table_t *table;   // Hash table that stores words
    unsigned size;    // Number of words stored in the dictionary
} dictionary_t;
```

In the end I am attempting to free all the memory I allocate by iterating through this structure, freeing all the nodes, then array, then the table and finally the dictionary. I believe my implementation is achieving this, however valgrind errors persist.

Here is my freeing implementation:

```
void table_free(table_t *table) {
        list_node_t *node;
        list_node_t *tempNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < table->length; i++) {
            if (table->array[i] != NULL) {
                if (table->array[i]->next == NULL) {//if only one node in array[i]'s linked list
                    free(table->array[i]);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    node = table->array[i];
                    while(node->next != NULL) {
                        tempNode = node->next;
                        free(node);
                        node = tempNode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < table->length; i++) {
            if (table->array[i] == NULL) { //free the spots I missed
                free(table->array[i]);
            }
        }
        free(table->array);
        free(table);
}

void dict_free(dictionary_t *dict) {
    table_free(dict->table);
    free(dict);
}
```

My big question is **when working with memory, is it sufficent to only deallocate it at the end of the program if you allocate it in functions?**

I ask because the valgrind errors are pointing me to other functions as well. My logic is that if I was freeing everything at the end correctly then memory leaks should not be an issue.

Here is the error:

```
==4046703== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4046703==     in use at exit: 60,928 bytes in 448 blocks
==4046703==   total heap usage: 2,031 allocs, 1,583 frees, 306,448 bytes allocated
==4046703== 
==4046703== 60,928 bytes in 448 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4046703==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4046703==    by 0x109C84: insert_word_into_table (dictionary.c:56)
==4046703==    by 0x109DD5: dict_insert (dictionary.c:95)
==4046703==    by 0x10A2B1: read_dict_from_text_file (dictionary.c:239)
==4046703==    by 0x1095E1: main (spell_check.c:105)
```

One approach I have taken to resolve this is free in the insert_word_into_table(); function which looks like this:

```
int insert_word_into_table(table_t *table, const char *word){
    int hsh_code = hash_code(word);
    int duplicateWordFlag = 0;
    //initialize the new node for the word
    list_node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));

    if (table->array[hsh_code] == NULL) {//if nothing is in the array
        table->array[hsh_code] = newNode;
        table->array[hsh_code]->next = NULL;
        strcpy(table->array[hsh_code]->word, word);
    } else {//if there is a node there
        list_node_t* i = table->array[hsh_code];
        while (i->next != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(word, i->word) == 0){
                duplicateWordFlag = -1;
            }
            i = i->next;
        }
        i->next = newNode;//new way
        strcpy(i->next->word, word);
        i->next->next = NULL;

    }
    //free(newNode); //my attempt to free it
    return duplicateWordFlag;
}
```

This approach did seem to put me in the right direction and produced the below message:

```
==4047436== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4047436==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4047436==   total heap usage: 2,031 allocs, 3,604 frees, 306,448 bytes allocated
==4047436== 
==4047436== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

However, when I free in this function (uncommenting the free(newNode) line) this now gives rise to this error here:

```
==4047436== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==4047436==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4047436==    by 0x10A03A: table_free (dictionary.c:161)
==4047436==    by 0x10A0F9: dict_free (dictionary.c:187)
==4047436==    by 0x109AEB: main (spell_check.c:229)
==4047436==  Address 0x4add510 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 136 free'd
==4047436==    at 0x484B27F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4047436==    by 0x109DB2: insert_word_into_table (dictionary.c:75)
==4047436==    by 0x109DE1: dict_insert (dictionary.c:95)
==4047436==    by 0x10A2BD: read_dict_from_text_file (dictionary.c:239)
==4047436==    by 0x1095E1: main (spell_check.c:105)
==4047436==  Block was alloc'd at
==4047436==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4047436==    by 0x109C84: insert_word_into_table (dictionary.c:56)
==4047436==    by 0x109DE1: dict_insert (dictionary.c:95)
==4047436==    by 0x10A2BD: read_dict_from_text_file (dictionary.c:239)
==4047436==    by 0x1095E1: main (spell_check.c:105)
```

The above valgrind message gives me the sense that I am freeing the memory and then trying to read/write to it, but I am unsure how to address this.

Could someone please help shine a light on this issue? I feel like I am misunderstanding memory allocation in C. Again, is it not sufficient to just free everything at the end?

Comment: Looks like you're not freeing the last node in a chain.

Comment: When your process terminates (i.e. it ends) the OS will release all the memory it had claimed. You should be freeing any memory you no longer need. Your data should have a defined lifetime and at the end of that lifetime any resources returned to the system.
As for your error you need to `free(tempNode)` after line 15 in your free implementation.

Comment: Just a comment: it doesn't make much sense to separate table_t and dictionary_t. They should be one struct. You would save a dynamic allocation and lots of indirections this way.

Comment: please post something one can compile. It seems you do not have a list, just a node. a list is not a node, a node is not a list. And as @n.m.couldbeanAI wrote, you may not even need table.